# How to handle Rest Exceptions in the new Twilio libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

So after some much needed updates to other areas of our software, we're updating our Twilio libraries to the latest version.

I'm looking through the API documentation, and I say this being a huge fan of how easy it was to get started originally with this API, but I'm finding the API reference a little lacking.

I wanted to better understand how the new 'CallResource' class works, but I can't find anything on it. Specifically, how it handles exceptions, if at all.

This is how it was handled in the old code:

```
            if (call.RestException == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(call.Sid.ToString()
                                + " " + call.StartTime.ToString()
                                + " " + call.Status.ToString());
                so.twillio_sid = call.Sid;
                so.status = call.Status;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                so.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.Failed;
                so.status = call.RestException.Message.ToString();
                callout.status = CalloutStatus.inprogressWaitingNext;
                db.SaveChanges();
                Debug.WriteLine(call.RestException.Message.ToString());
            }
```

How should I go about checking if the call was initiated successfully in the new interfaces?

Comment: You should be able to use Status property of CallResource.

Comment: Do you know of an API document I can reference? The statuses seem to represent conditions different than the failure conditions that'd cause a RestException (as per the old API).

Comment: If you are using the new version then you need to follow the new documentation. Somethings which was happening in old API might not be true with the new API. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/next-generation-csharp-helper-library-release.html

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-csharp

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - The first place I went was the documentation. I'm here because the documentation was incomplete. Did you read the link you posted?

Comment: The blog post did end up helping. Had to go down the rabbit hole though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out the new approach is:

```
try
{
    //make a call
} 
catch(ApiException e)
{
    //handle exception state here
}
```

This document ended up being where the answer lies. Unfortunately the new code samples don't contain any error handling.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`src/Twilio/Exceptions/TwilioException.cs`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/main/src/Twilio/Exceptions/TwilioException.cs).

```cs
try
{
    var verificationCheck = VerificationCheckResource.Create(
        to: "jsmith@example.com",
        code: "123456",
        pathServiceSid: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    );
}
catch (TwilioException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"code failed >> e = {e}");
}
```